Не работает переход по постам в кастомных таксономиях

зарегистрировал новый тип поста:
 function my_custom_post_types(){
 // Добавляем taxonomy ангары
     register_taxonomy( 'category_hangars', [ 'post_hangars' ], [
         'label'                 => 'Категории ангаров', // определяется параметром $labels->name
         'labels'                => [
             'name'              => 'Категории ангаров',
             'singular_name'     => 'Категория ангаров',
             'search_items'      => 'Искать категории',
             'all_items'         => 'Все категории',
             'popular_items'     => 'Популярные категории',
             'view_item '        => 'Просмотреть категорию',
             'parent_item'       => 'Род. категория',
             'parent_item_colon' => 'Род. категория:',
             'edit_item'         => 'Ред. категорию',
             'update_item'       => 'Обновить категорию',
             'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить категорию',
             'new_item_name'     => 'Новая категория',
             'menu_name'         => 'Категории ангаров',
             'back_to_items'     => '← Вернуться в категории ',
         ],
         'description'           => 'Рубрики для ангаров', // описание таксономии
         'public'                => true,
         'publicly_queryable'    => true, // равен аргументу public
         'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
         'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
         'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
         'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
         'hierarchical'          => true,
         'rewrite'               => array('slug'=>'post_hangars', 'hierarchical'=>false, 'with_front'=>false, 'feed'=>false ),
         'query_var'             => true, // название параметра запроса
         'capabilities'          => array(),
         'meta_box_cb'           => null, // html метабокса. callback: `post_categories_meta_box` или `post_tags_meta_box`. false — метабокс отключен.
         'show_admin_column'     => false, // авто-создание колонки таксы в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
     'show_in_rest'          => true, // добавить в REST API
     'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
 ] );
 // Добавляем ангары
 register_post_type( 'post_hangars', [
     'label'                  => 'Ангары',
     'labels'                 => [
         'name'               => 'Ангары', // основное название для типа записи
         'singular_name'      => 'Ангар', // название для одной записи этого типа
         'add_new'            => 'Добавить ангар', // для добавления новой записи
         'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новый ангар', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
         'edit_item'          => 'Добавить:', // Заголовок к кнопке "добавить" в редакторе
         'new_item'           => 'Новый ангар', // текст новой записи
         'view_item'          => 'Смотреть ангар', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
         'search_items'       => 'Искать ангар', // для поиска по этим типам записи
         'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
         'parent_item_colon'  => '',
         'menu_name'          => 'Ангары', // название меню
         'all_items'          => 'Все ангары',
     ],
     'description'            => 'Каталог Ангары',
     'public'                 => true,
     'publicly_queryable'     => true,
     'show_ui'                => true,
     'show_in_menu'           => true,
     'show_in_rest'           => true, // добавить в REST API, чтоб работал редактор Gutenberg
     'query_var'              => true,
     'rewrite'                => true,
     'capability_type'        => 'post',
     'has_archive'            => true,
     'hierarchical'           => false,
     'menu_position'          => null,
     'menu_icon'              => 'dashicons-cart',
     'supports'               => ['title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'],
 ] );

}

создал в админке в новом post_type рубрику: Ангары из металлочерепицы(hangars-mch)

создал в этой рубрике посты. И прикрепил к кастомному шаблону.


/*
Template Name: Карточка test
Template Post Type: post, post_hangars
*/
На странице они выводятся, но перейти на них в отличии от стандартных постов я не могу.
По ссылке переходит: сайт/post_hangars/пост/ но отображает главную страницу.

что такое «кастюмный»?


кастомный созданный с помощью register_post_type()



И прикрепил к кастомному шаблону.


Нужно не "прикреплять", а делать кастомный шаблон темы.

В register_post_type не указана таксономия.


PS. И не стоит в аргументах функций писать что и так по дефолту. Писать лучше только то, что изменяется.
PSS. И после создания кастомных сущностей нужно зайти в настройки пермалинков.


он и так сделан, а прикреплен и прикреплен к нему в админке.
это не обязательный параметр, главное в таксономии указан post_type
в пермалинки заходил множество раз не помогает



Ты не то сделал. 2. Ну если ты такой умный - не стоит и спрашивать (главное что не нужно напихал, а что нужно нет и спорит...)


Спрашивал потому-то нужна была помощь, а не чтоб кто то умничал. А от таких помощников только репутация сайта падает.
Разобрался сам, может кому поможет в 'rewrite' поставил значение true в register_taxonomy(тут был конфликт ЧПУ), чтоб получать значение по умолчанию.
А в register_post_type в 'rewrite' добавил значение с нужным slag: ['slug' => 'card_hangars'], но можно и по умолчанию true.
